# Replacing numbers ending in 3 and 7 in a string

Tags: python

Write a program that generates and prints a list of n elements (n informed by the user) containing the natural numbers (starting with 1) and replacing multiples of 3 by the word 'ping', multiples of 7 by the word 'pong', and multiples of 3 and 7 by the word 'ping-pong'

Here is the code for that

```
result = []
number = eval(input("Enter a whole number: "))
for index in range(number):
    if index % 7 == 0 and index % 3 == 0:
        result.append("ping-pong")
    elif index % 3 == 0:
        result.append("ping")
    elif index % 7 == 0:
        result.append("pong")
    else:
        result.append(index)
print(result) == 0
```

Now also replaces numbers ending in 3 by the word ‘PING’ and numbers ending in 7 by the word ‘PONG’ this I am not sure how to go about doing.

Comment: You really shouldn't parse to an integer using `eval`; use the `int` function instead (`int(input('Enter a whole number: '))`)

Comment: the use of `eval` is confusing, why is used exactly?

Comment: @SSj.Luffy Force evaluating numbers to `int`. However, that should never be done. `eval` should always be avoided. Just cast to `int` instead => `int(input())`

Comment: Convert the input to a string and grab the last index, testing it against 7 and 3.

Comment: why not print the output as you generate it, instead of trying to append to result ?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to make your code do what you want while doing as few modifications to it as possible.

- Do **NOT** use `eval`. Ever. Bad, bad, bad `eval`. To cast an string to an int, use `int()`.
- Your code was starting at 0 when it was asked that it started at 1, I
  changed the range.
- To know the last digit, I calculated the number modulo 10, based on the clever comment by @Renuka Deshmukh. Other less clever solutions could have been to check the end of the number casted as a string, with `str(index).endswith("7")` or `str(index)[-1] == "7"`, for example.
- What was your `print(result) == 0` trying to do? I removed the `==0`.

Here is the resulting code:

```
result = []
number = int(input("Enter a whole number: "))
for index in range(1,number+1):
    if index % 7 == 0 and index % 3 == 0:
        result.append("ping-pong")
    elif index % 3 == 0 or index % 10 == 3:
        result.append("ping")
    elif index % 7 == 0 or index % 10 == 7:
        result.append("pong")
    else:
        result.append(index)
print(result)
```

Comment: Instead of converting the number to string try index % 10 == 3 and index % 10 == 7. Converting to string is not needed.

Comment: Quite right. I'm too used to bruteforcing stuff, I can't even to basic maths.